# ¿Cómo generar un número binario aleatorio?

Tags: python, binario

Estoy haciendo un código que me genere un número binario aleatorio de cierta longitud, pero no sé si esta bien generado. En lugar de que me lo genere como un número como tal, me genera una lista con 0s y 1s. ¿Está bien generado o se hace de otra forma?

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```
import random

binario = random.choices([0,1], k=22)
print(binario)
```

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta es: genera escenarios de prueba, pruébalo y comprueba la salida cada vez. Si pasa tus escenarios de prueba, está bien generado.

Comment: ¿Qué tipos de escenarios debería crear para probarlo?

Comment: Prueba generando 1.000 números binarios. Calcula su promedio, su desviación estándar, etc. y revisalos contra la definición de aleatorio.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando ejecuto el código me sale el numero de esta forma. Por ejemplo si lo hago con k=10 me sale [1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0], y tengo entendido que debería ser algo como '1001101000'

Comment: @EdGar. [1, 0, 0 , 1 ...] y '1001...' son dos representaciones del mismo número. Usa el formato que te resulte más adecuado para el resto del trabajo.

Answer (score 4):

esta misma pregunta la respondí en otro foro:

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
import random

binario =random.choices([0,1], k=10)
```

bueno, una forma sería con join y compresión de listas

```
print(''.join([str(_) for _ in binario]))
```

otra posible forma sería con map

```
print("".join(map(str,binario)))
```

y por supuesto que eso sería trampòso porque un binario de 10 valores que comience con 1 o más 0 es ilógico
para eso haría:

```
import random
numero = random.randint(512,1024)
```

que son los valores posibles que pueden tener como binarios

y para mostrarlo simplemente un format

```
print(f'{bin(numero)[2:]}')
```

Comment: Excelente. Las ecuaciones para el límite inferior y el límite superior de `randint()` serían: **inferior:** `2 ** (length - 1)`. **superior:** `2 ** length - 1`

Comment: Dos pequeñas mejoras: si se aplica `random.choices` a la cadena `"01"` no necesitarás luego convertir a cadena los elementos de la lista. Por otro lado, para pasar a binario en el último print, se puede usar directamente el formato `f'{numero:b}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una [distribución binomial](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribuci%C3%B3n_binomial) con `Numpy` usando su función `np.random.binomial()`, con esta función puedes controlar el número de **unos y de ceros**

```
import numpy as np

frac = 0.5

np.random.binomial(n=1, p=frac, size=22)

#Los unimos
"".join(map(str, np.random.binomial(n=1, p=frac, size=22)))
```

**Salida** `'1001100100010110111111'`

En este caso hemos creado una distribución de unos y ceros de 22 números. Con una probabilidad del 0.5% para ambos números. Si bajamos el parámetro `p` entrarán más ceros, si lo subimos habrá más unos.

Después iteramos por todos los valores de la lista con `map()` para convertirlos a `str` y por último les hacemos un `join()`.